# Weird performance issue with MySQL stored procedure that does many INSERTs into a temporary table

Tags: mysql, performance, stored-procedures, sql-insert

Revised and improved question:

I've got a weird problem with my MySQL servers. Here's an example, reduced to the bare problem:

```
drop procedure if exists temp_test;
create procedure temp_test()
begin
  declare i int default 0;

  drop temporary table if exists temp_table;
  create temporary table temp_table(x int) engine = memory;

  while i < 400 do
    insert into temp_table(x) values (i);
    set i = i + 1;
  end while; 

  select * from temp_table;
end;
```

Calling this takes about 1 second which is way, way longer than I would expect. BUT! This is on a remote server in a datacenter some 1500km away (Amazon RDS). If I run this on my local MySQL instance, this takes less than 0.1 seconds. I can rule out network latency - running a simple `select 1;` on the remote server takes only 0.15 seconds.

Weirder yet, for a minute, the remote server was just as fast (plus the network latency)! And then it went back to being slow again. But it's not loaded - this is just a test server and I'm the only one accessing it right now.

What's going on? Where should I look?

(Preemptive reply: no, in the full problem I cannot reduce it to a single `INSERT ... SELECT`)

Comment: What storage engine do you use for the temporary table? You could try using the MEMORY storage engine, to avoid the overhead of durable table writes. E.g. `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ... ENGINE=MEMORY;`

Comment: Also it's hard to make any specific recommendations when you haven't shown the procedure code that you use for the cursor, and you haven't shown the `SELECT` that returns 40k rows, and you haven't shown the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for your temp table.

Comment: @BillKarwin - Oh, I forgot to mention - Yes, I do use `MEMORY` engine for the temp table. OK, I'll post the code, just a moment.

Comment: @BillKarwin - There you go, full source code (minus slight anonymization for table/field names)

Comment: Well I see the query has `where time >= dateFrom and time < dateTo order by f3, time`, which will be forced to use a filesort, because it can't use an index both for the time filtering and for the sorting. Since it's matching 40,000 rows it might need to do the filesort on disk (check `show status like 'Sort_merge_passes'` to see if it did use the disk).

Comment: So the performance issue might not be due to the cursor or the temp table at all, it might just be that it's costly to do that select query. Try profiling an execution of the query directly, without using the stored proc. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-profile.html

Comment: @Bill Karwin - As I said, if I remove JUST the `insert` statements from the procedure, but leave everything else in, the runtime drops to 0.5s. I also then tried removing the `order by` (in addition to removing the `insert`s), but paradoxically it actually increased the runtime to 0.7s. Probably because the larger `set` statement got executed more often. Yes, I did run all attempts several times to see that their runtime remains stable.

Comment: @BillKarwin - More weirdness uncovered. Please take a look at the latest update.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out myself!

The remote server is an Amazon RDS server. I didn't think it was important but apparently they are infamous for slow performance of their binary replication logs (as a side note, why we have that enabled for our *test* server that will never be replicated is beyond me, but whatever).

You would think that a **temporary table with memory storage engine** doesn't use that or touch the disk in any way, but you would be wrong. Apparently, it all still gets to the binlog and it all gets replicated too.

Now, MySQL has an option called `sync_binlog` - it's an integer telling after how many transactions to flush the binlog from memory buffers to disk. 0 means that OS decides when it wants to flush the file (as it does for most files); 1 means that it's flushed after every transaction; 2 means every other transaction, etc. The default is **1** - flush after every transaction.

The final piece of the puzzle is the fact that the MEMORY storage engine doesn't support transactions. So every INSERT is really a whole transaction as far as MySQL is concerned. You can see where this is going.

The solution was counterintuitive, but effective - change from `MEMORY` to `InnoDB` and put it all in a transaction. Boom. The whole thing now takes 0.2s, and that's including the 0.15s network latency. That's more like it! :)